# Automating the install of PostgreSQL from Shell

Tags: sql, bash, shell, postgresql

When my Debian server deploys it can run a shell script so I wanted to make one to install postgreSQL, create a role, create two databases and then import a schema into one.

Can anyone please look at this code and tell me if I have done an ok job?

```
 # POSTGRES
apt-get install -y postgresql
echo "CREATE ROLE deploy LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '$APP_DB_PASS';" | sudo -u postgres psql
su postgres -c "createdb db1 --owner deploy"
su postgres -c "createdb db2 --owner deploy"
service postgresql reload

# IMPORT SQL
psql --username=postgres spider < /etc/schema.sql
```

Comment: Personally, I like to use long-options in scripts, even for "obvious" options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using `psql -c command` for the first invocation of `psql`, or better yet, just use the `createuser` command.

For the second invocation, you might want `psql -f /etc/schema.sql`.  I would also suggest using the `--single-transaction` flag, so that in the unlikely event of an error, the failure will be blatantly obvious since the `spider` database will be empty.  (I assume you will also create a database named `spider` sometime before trying to import data into it.)